# Return 0 in columns if no rows selected in Oracle

Tags: oracle

While I am executing a query in Oracle DB it returns 0 rows. I need to return column values as 0 if no rows are selected. Please find the attached sample query.

```
select NVL(staff,0), NVL(code,0)
       from stafftable
      where staffid= 123
        and code in (112, 251)
        and closedate is not null
        and rownum<2
        order by opendate desc;
```

If no rows selected I need below result:

```
NVL(staff,0)      NVL(code,0)
0                 0
```

I have tried NVL(), coalsce() not able to get the expected result.

Comment: Do you ***need*** the `staff` and `code` values to come from the same row?  *(At present, if there are multiple matching rows, you choose one at random.)*  If the `staff` value and the `code` value came from different rows, would that be okay?  If so, just use `NVL(MAX(staff),0), NVL(MAX(code),0)` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=057ce16145c9d004b2c525700747d2b3

Comment: @MatBailie You can fix the issue of multiple matching rows by adding the OP's `rownum<2` filter and then there will never be more than 1 row to aggregate [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=985cfec7a14266539d79cb4986fc93e5) (whether using `ROWNUM` without previously ordering the data gives the expected answer is a different question though).

Comment: @MatBailie@MT0 I edited the query above. Thank you.

Comment: @KannanK `ROWNUM` is applied before the `ORDER BY` clause so your edit does not make sense as you are asking Oracle to only get the first matching row and then order that single row by `opendate`. If you want to get the latest `OPENDATE` then you need to `ORDER BY` first and then filter on `ROWNUM` afterwards (using nested sub-queries).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have tried NVL(), coalsce() not able to get the expected result.

Because it really didn't return any result, so we might get empty result

WE can try to use `CTE` with `UNION ALL`

one is for your filter result, another is for your default result from empty result

```
WITH cte AS ( 
      select staff, code
       from stafftable
      where staffid= 123
        and code in (112, 251)
        and closedate is not null
        and rownum<2
)
SELECT staff, code
FROM cte
UNION ALL 
SELECT 0 , 0 
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM cte 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `UNION ALL` a single row with zeros and then, from Oracle 12, `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`:

```sql
SELECT NVL(staff,0) AS staff,
       NVL(code,0) AS code
FROM   stafftable
WHERE  staffid= 123
AND    code in (112, 251)
AND    closedate is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 0 FROM DUAL
-- ORDER BY staff DESC, code DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

This will only perform one table/index scan on the `stafftable`.

If you want to do the same in Oracle 11 then use a sub-query and filter the outer query on `ROWNUM`:

```sql
SELECT staff,
       code
FROM   (
  SELECT NVL(staff,0) AS staff,
         NVL(code,0) AS code
  FROM   stafftable
  WHERE  staffid= 123
  AND    code in (112, 251)
  AND    closedate is not null
UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 0 FROM DUAL
-- ORDER BY staff DESC, code DESC
)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

---

If you want to order the rows by `OPENDATE` then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT NVL(staff,0) AS staff,
         NVL(code,0) AS code
  FROM   stafftable
  WHERE  staffid= 123
  AND    code in (112, 251)
  AND    closedate is not null
  ORDER BY opendate DESC
)
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 0 FROM DUAL
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT NVL(staff,0) AS staff,
           NVL(code,0) AS code
    FROM   stafftable
    WHERE  staffid= 123
    AND    code in (112, 251)
    AND    closedate is not null
    ORDER BY opendate DESC
  )
UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 0 FROM DUAL
)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=942699c2be5b7781ccf97e2e143008b1)*

Comment: upvote!! `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` is a nice solution

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with max, assuming the values in staff are positive:

```
select max(staff) staff, max(code) code
FROM (
       select staff, code
         from stafftable
        where staffid= 123
          and code in (112, 251)
          and closedate is not null
          and rownum<2 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 0 , 0 FROM dual
    )
```